# Flex & Flash mobile application Developemt

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

i want to learn how to develop mobile application in flash n flex

which book is good ?? n pls tell if any good online tutorial are available or not 
i am just beginner ,i never desined any mobile application but have experi

Answer (score 0):

You should go for [`Adobe's online tutorial`](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/mobile/). Try [building your `own` application](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/twitter-trends.html) on mobile Its for free.

Some recommended books :

- [Developing Android Applications with Flex 4.5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449305377)
- [Developing Android Applications with Adobe AIR (Adobe Developer Library)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449394825)
- [Professional Flash Mobile Development: Creating Android and iPhone Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470620072)
- [Developing Blackberry Tablet Applications with Flex 4.5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449305563)